# Getting Can't load SQLite3.dll! not found error with Autohotkey

Tags: sqlite, autohotkey

I am getting sqlite3.dll not found error at Autohotkey app. I already have sqlite3.dll file in the Project at [sqlite3.dll](https://github.com/sl5net/global-IntelliSense-everywhere/blob/master/Source/Lib/sqlite3.dll)

The error is produced here [SQLite_L.ahk#L107](https://github.com/sl5net/global-IntelliSense-everywhere/blob/master/Source/Lib/SQLite_L.ahk#L107) :

```
if(FileExist(sqliteDllPath)){
      DLL := DllCall("LoadLibrary", "Str", sqliteDllPath)
      if(!DLL)
         throw Exception("Can't load " . sqliteDllPath . "! (token:18-10-12_11-52. BTW DllCall is in AHK v2 is case sensitive)", -1)
```

Within this application, i worked without problem at 
64-Bit Windows 10 10.0 lenovo t540p (Admin-Account).
Also worked for others in the circle of friends (not Admin-Account).
A user reported my this error into the AHK-Forum.

My first Steps:

1. During my recherche i found: 
   [DllCall is in AHK v2 is case sensitive][3]
   I guess he'll use the version 2. 
   So everywhere I changed SQLite3.dll to sqlite3.dll
2. But Today i got this error at another Laptop (fresh downloadet from github). 
   I have therefore unpacked the project in different directories.

   [3]: https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=3280 "DllCall is in AHK v2 is case sensitive". No success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the SQLite dll is [64-bit DLL](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) (sha1: 9fad624c1aa1c0c9ba20230f2e176fac305edac5)

but installed was a [32-bit AHK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gmpU.png)

[A_Is64bitOS](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm)  [v1.1.08+]: Contains 1 (true) if the OS is 64-bit

[A_PtrSize](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm)  [v1.0.90+]: Contains the size of a pointer, in bytes. if the AHK is 64-bit 8.

If ahk is updated to 64 bit, this error message disappears.
Ideally, this should also be checked in the script.

```
ahkIs64version := (A_PtrSize=8 ? "64-bit" : "32-bit")
MsgBox % "Script is MsgBox % "Script is  . (ahkIs64version ? "64-bit" : "32-bit")
if(!ahkIs64version)
    MsgBox,% "Error: AHK Version (32-bit) not match to Sqlite Version (64 bit). Please update your ahk-Version or choose another Sqlite Version"
```